# How to pass two Json lists from Java Servlet to HTML page?

Tags: java, angularjs, json, servlets

In my `HTML` page I would like to be able to distinguish between `two lists` that come from the `servlet`,so I want to send each one independent from the other but both are in the **same response** of the `servlet`.

I use the following code in the `servlet` to pass one list: `Coll1Json` :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String Coll1Json = gson.toJson(Coll1, UAppConstants.CHANNEL_COLLECTION);
String Coll2Json = gson.toJson(Coll2, UAppConstants.CHANNEL_COLLECTION);
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println(Coll1Json);                    //here only Coll1Json is passed
writer.close();
```

I want to send both `Coll1Json` and `Coll2Json`.

**How** can I solve this and **how** can I read both of them in the `HTML` page `controller` after sending?

Thanks

Comment: combine them into one json array

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Wrapper class and add both `json` strings inside it, e.g.:

```
public class Response{
  //constructors
  private String Coll1Json;
  private String Coll2Json; 
  //Setters and Getters
}
```

In the code, you can simply do the following:

```
String Coll1Json = gson.toJson(Coll1, UAppConstants.CHANNEL_COLLECTION);
String Coll2Json = gson.toJson(Coll2, UAppConstants.CHANNEL_COLLECTION);
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.println(new Response(Coll1Json, Coll2Json));                    
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the JOSN's to the array list and then convert the ArrayList to JSON response.

```
    List<DataObject> objList = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
    objList.add(Coll1Json );
    objList.add(Coll2Json );       
    // Convert the object to a JSON string
    String json = new Gson().toJson(objList);
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.println(Coll1Json);                    
    writer.close();
```